# PHP - alias - permanent domain between referers

Tags: php, alias

I have to create an alias script. In this script I can add someone domain (for example http://facebook.com) and then, the content from website facebook.com should be available at my new domain domain which I can specify in this script.

Example form:

**New domain:** http://my-new-domain.com

**Website:**
http://facebook.com

and then content from facebook.com should be available at domain: http://my-new-domain.com/

And I know how I can do it but I don't know how to set a permanent domain in address bar in browser? For example, when I visit my new generated domain: http://my-new-domain.com/ I can see a main page content of facebook.com website but when I click "settings" ( https://www.facebook.com/settings ) - there will be redirect from my new domain: http://my-new-domain.com/ to https://www.facebook.com/settings. How to make this redirect from my new domain http://my-new-domain.com/ without leave this domain: http://my-new-domain.com/ ?

So finally when I click something url, the domain in address bar shouldn't change but script should get the content from clicked url?

I searched topics on stackoverflow.com but I found nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for a proxy module which can forward requests coming to your web app to a different site.

Assuming you are using Apache web server, apache contains a module called mod_proxy which addresses such requirements.

You can find more info here.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: So I can do it in .htaccess file? Can you give me an example?

Comment: There are few examples available in the link provided under Basic Examples section..

Comment: `ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy "*">
  Require host internal.example.com
</Proxy>` - so I ahve to add this code to htaccess file and change `internal.example.com` for `facebook.com` in this case?